# Bootstrap <i> icons being overridden by <em> in refinery editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, refinerycms

I am using refinery branch 2.0-stable with twitter bootstrap and rails 3.1.

I've tried adding a bootstrap icon to a refinery page html using the following syntax:

```
<i class="icon-caret-left"></i>
```

When I save the page, the  tags are overridden with  tags.

Any ideas of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the tag that the class is applied to doesn't really matter at all so I used

```
<span class="icon-caret-left></span>
```

Hopefully that will help someone